# How to remove the selected checkboxes from the table

Tags: jquery

Under my stocks , i select some checkboxes .

My question is how do i remove the selected checkboxes from the table when clicked on the Fetch All button??

This is my code

```
$(document).on('click', '.fetchall', function (e) {
        var array = $('#greaterquan .mycheckbox:checked').map(function () {
            return this.nextSibling.nodeValue;
        }).get();


    });
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/n6q9mtdp/4/

please let me know how to do this ??

Comment: I tried it this way $('#greaterquan .mycheckbox:checked tr').remove();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably the simpliest way in this case to remove `<tr>` which contain a checked box:

```
$('#greaterquan .mycheckbox:checked').closest('tr').remove();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/454gd796/)

Answer (score 0):

You also can try this code, hopes this help:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fetchall', function (e) {
    $('#greaterquan .mycheckbox').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        }

    });
});
```